# how to generate cells using macros in excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Dim i, last As Integer
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To last        
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then

        Range("A1:C").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Application.Run "updatecc"
        Range("A1:c").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Application.Run "updatecc"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Help needed here, I want to add cells dependent upon data in cells of sheet1 to sheet2.
It is copying only first a1:c1 values.
I need to copy from sheet1 and paste it in sheet2 and generate cells.

Comment: This is not a solution but be aware that `Dim i, last As Integer` does not declare both as integer. It only declares `last` as integer but `i` remains variant. To declare both as integer you need `Dim i As Integer, last As Integer`. This is a major difference between VB where `Dim i, last As Integer` declares both as integer and VBA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the first `Range("A1:C").Select` by `Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,3))`
This will select columns A to C of the row that you are checking.